# How to get specific row data from 3 table using foreign key?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in one database.
3 table screenshot:
[image: 3 table screenshot]

Then I declared foreign key from first table ID to second table ID. And second table runway_no to third table runway_no.
relational database model screenshot:
[image: relational database model screenshot]

Now I want to call by the only id and get all tables data (specific row) in one table.

I tried this,

```
    SELECT
airport.id, airport.airport_name, runway.id, runway.runway_no, runway.runway_length, runway.runway_width
FROM
airport
INNER JOIN
runway
ON
airport.id=runway.id
```

Here every data is showing.
screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

But the problem is I do not figure out this How to select specific ID and will show only those id rows.
like this(screenshot):
[image: like this(screenshot)]

Comment: With the way you've set up the relations the `surface_type` and `surface_condition` data should be part of the `runway` table, not in a separate table of their own. Why have you used `varchar(255)` when runway numbers are no more than three characters long? Note also that one runway will, almost without exception, have two runway numbers: 30L is the same piece of tarmac as 12R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `where [conditions]` to the end of your query to get what you want:

For example, to get only the data where id=2

```
SELECT
airport.id, airport.airport_name, runway.id, runway.runway_no, runway.runway_length, runway.runway_width
FROM
airport
INNER JOIN
runway
ON
airport.id=runway.id 
where airport.id=2
```